# Printing Webview Content to Airprinter with page breaks

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, ipad, airprint

I am trying to print webview content to airprinter. Everything works fine except I am not getting page breaks. I have searched in many forums but I didn't found the solution.

**This is my HTML Template**

```
<html><body>
<h1 style='display:block; page-break-after:always;'>PAGE 1</h1>
<h1 style='display:block; page-break-after:always;'>PAGE 2</h1>
<h1 style='display:block; page-break-after:always;'>PAGE 3</h1>
</body></html>
```

Webview is showing page break properly.

**But when Printing function is called I am getting this**

[image]

```
@IBAction func printDoc(_ sender: Any) {

        let pic = UIPrintInteractionController.shared
        let printInfo : UIPrintInfo = UIPrintInfo(dictionary: nil)  
        printInfo.outputType = UIPrintInfoOutputType.general
        printInfo.jobName = "test"
        pic.printInfo = printInfo
        pic.printFormatter = webview.viewPrintFormatter()
        pic.showsPageRange = false    
        pic.present(animated: true, completionHandler: nil)
    }
```

Please tell me how to have page break when printing to air printer.